# On Pascal’s Triangle: Combinatorics, Leibniz rule, and Binomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I’ve always been fascinated by connections between different areas of maths, even though I rarely figure out *why* such connections are there in the first place.

One of them involves the Pascal triangle... its construction is simple, and yet its numbers appear when computing powers of a sum, like $(a + b)^n$, or when counting how many combinations of $n$ elements in groups of $k$ are there, or when calculating the derivative of a product $(fg)^{(n)}$... they seem completely different tasks.
Is there a way of seeing *why* the Pascal triangle *has* to be related to these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the three examples you give here, it turns out that at the heart of each process, we are essentially doing the same thing, and that 'thing' is exactly the method for constructing Pascal's triangle.

Let look at expanding $(a+b)^n=(a+b)(a+b)...(a+b)$. You may have heard of the 'Smiley face method' to expand $(a+b)(a+b)$, where we multiply the first $a$ by both the $a$ and $b$ in the second bracket, then do the same for $b$ (essentially the same as rewriting as $a(a+b)+b(a+b)$).

A similar thing happens for $(a+b)^n$. We can rewrite as $a(a+b)^{n-1}+b(a+b)^{n-1}$, then do the same for each $(a+b)^{n-1}$. We would then have a long list of products of $a$ and $b$ and adding them together gives us $(a+b)^n$. In this way, every sequence of $k$ $a$'s and $(n-k)$ $b$'s that is corresponds to a single $a^kb^{n-k}$ term in the expansion, so the number of ways we can make these lists is the coefficient of $a^kb^{n-k}$.

That is how the coefficients in $(a+b)^n$ is related to the number of number of ways you can choose $k$ elements from a set of $n$, since making a list of $k$ $a$'s and $(n-k)$ $b$'s is the same as choosing which $k$ positions in the list will only be $a$'s, or which $(n-k)$ positions will only be $b$'s. This is also why ${n\choose k}={n\choose n-k}$.

Exactly the same thing happens in $(fg)^{(n)}$. The coefficient of $f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$ is the number of ways we can differentiate $f$ $k$ times and $g$ $(n-k)$ times, i.e. making a list of $k$ [differentiate $f$]s and $(n-k)$ [differentiate $g$]s.

Now to see how this relates to the iterative process that generates Pascal's triangle. Here are two ways we could look at this:

1. Each number in Pascal's triangle is the sum of the two numbers above it, which are the sums of the two numbers above those, and so on. This means that every number in Pascal's triangle has been formed by adding the first 1 onto itself multiple times. The first 1 initially splits and distributes two 1s onto the second row. Then each of those 1s split again and distribute onto the third row, except they both contribute to the middle entry so that becomes 2. We can interpret this as each number is the sum of all the ways 1 has travelled down the triangle e.g. in the case of the 2 in the second row, 1 travels left and the right, or right and then left. These two paths leading to the same place mean the value at this point is 2. Hence the number at $n\choose k$ is the number of paths 1 can travel to get to the corresponding point i.e. now many lists of $k$ [left]'s and $(n-k)$ [right]'s can we make.
2. Another way we could look at this is by considering the inductive nature. Pascal's triangle is generated by ${n\choose k}={n-1\choose k}+{n-1\choose k+1}$. $(a+b)^n$=$a(a+b)^{n-1}+b(a+b)^{n-1}$, so the coefficient of $a^kb^{n-k}$ could be viewed as the coefficient of $a^{k-1}b^{n-k}$ in $(a+b)^{n-1}$ (from $a(a+b)^{n-1}$) added to the coefficient of $a^{k}b^{n-k-1}$ (from $b(a+b)^{n-1}$). In other words,
   \begin{align}
   {n\choose k}={n-1\choose n-(k+1)}+{n-1\choose k}={n-1\choose k+1}+{n-1\choose k}
   \end{align}
   where the last equality comes from the symmetry we found earlier of ${n\choose k}={n\choose n-k}$.

And this is exactly the iterative method we use to generate Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 3):

Note each row of the Pascal triangle is a sum of two copies of the previous row, shifted by one position. This corresponds to binomials multiplication, e.g. for the row number 3:

```
    1 2 1
   1 3 3 1
```

is arithmetically

```
     1 2 1
+  1 2 1
==========
   1 3 3 1
```

and for $(a+b)^3 = (a+b)^2 \cdot (a+b)$ we have

$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
& & (a^2 & +2\ ab & + b^2) \\
\times & & & (a & +\ b\,) \\
\hline
& & a^2b & +2\ ab^2 & + b^3\ \\
+ & a^3 & +2\ a^2b & +\ \ \ ab^2 \\
\hline
& a^3 & +3\ a^2b & +3\ ab^2 & + b^3\ 
 \end{array}$$

where the same shift and addition appears in coefficients.

The same recurrence appears when constructing combinations (subsets). Let's denote the number of combinations with $\binom n k.$ For any set you have one empty combination and one full combination - those correspond to the left and the right edge of the Pascal's triangle (and a special case of the empty set, which has just one, empty combination, represented by the topmost $1$ in the triangle). For each 'internal' term, that is a combination of $k$ items from $n$, where $0<k<n$, you can either include the $n$-th element in the combination (and then combine $k-1$ elements from remaining $n-1$) or not include it (and then combine $k$ elements from remaining $n-1$):
$$\binom nk = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}k$$
which is a sum of two neighbor elements from the previous row of the triangle.

A derivative of product is $$(fg)' = f'g + fg'$$ When you apply it recursively, it resolves to the same pattern of shift-and-add which is in the Pascal triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your two ideas and then show that they correspond.  Suppose we said:

- Pascal's triangle can be defined by $f(n,k)=f(n-1,k-1)+f(n,k-1)$ for $0 < k < n$ and $f(n,0)=f(n,n)=1$
- The binomial coefficient can be defined by  ${n \choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ for $0 \le k \le n$

You can then show

- ${n-1 \choose k-1}+{n \choose k-1} $ $= \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}$ $= \frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}\left(k + (n-k)\right) $ $= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}= {n \choose k}$
- ${n \choose 0}=\frac{n!}{0!n!}=1$ and ${n \choose n}=\frac{n!}{n!0!}=1$

so the two definitions correspond